# How would I change this LINQ query to the method way instead of the SQL looking way

Tags: c#, linq

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(await movies.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Can you not just do `movies = _context.Movie.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));` ?

Comment: @RobJarvis - No. The obvious case is if `searchString` is `null`. `String.Contains` blows up if you pass it `null`.

Comment: @GertArnold - They're talking about [query vs method syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq). Presumably the query syntax in the question (`from m in _context.Movie select m`) is the "SQL looking way".

Comment: Well, @BrootsWaymb, I was just assuming you would keep that line inside the conditional block as in your example. My point was that there is no need to do the first part when you can just reference the _context.Movie collection directly instead of running a LINQ query first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the below if you just want a list of movies from your context as a list.

```
var movies = _context.Movie.ToList();
```

You can also do something like below, which does about the same thing but more closely resembles your query syntax.

```
var movies = _context.Movie.Select(s => s);
```

So your code could be something like below.

```
  var movies = _context.Movie.Select(s => s);

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
  {
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
  }

  return View(await movies.ToListAsync());
```